# My real device has an IMEI of 012345678912345 - why?

Tags: imei

I recently found one of my old Android devices (Orbo Jr. w/Rockchip ZX-2926D, Android 4.4.2), charged it, and turned it on. After exploring the settings, I found it had an IMEI number of `012345678912345` - definitely not unique. After some research, it seemed to belong to Android-x86 devices with tons of hints to Virtualbox and QEMU in its system file names.

Looking up the number on [imei.info](http://imei.info) ends up with "Invalid number".

I would dial `*#07#` on its Phone, but there is no phone. Although (about every 6 months or more), it gets malware calling itself "Phone".

It has been factory reset twice before looking at the IMEI number.

I found how to (semi) change it [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-imei-changer-t2847187), but am having an issue getting it to root (even if I wanted to use it, I couldn't). Towelroot says "your device is not supported", and KingRoot says "Rooting error".

Why does this device has an invalid IMEI?

Comment: Wow, that's a bogus IMEI and a HALF. Probably down to it being a Chinese offbrand? A Rogue "Phone" app would be related too, at a guess.